# anchor download link not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have used this

```
<A HREF="/admin/con/image/StudentImportFileTemplate_Create.csv" download="StudentImportFileTemplate_Create.csv">Download</A>
```

I have added `download` attribute for chrome but its is not supported for firefox

This is working fine in IE and chrome file is getting downloaded Can anyone explain me how to get it work for firefox also.

Comment: Looks like it was recently worked on: http://javascript-reverse.tumblr.com/post/37056936789/html5-download-attribute

Comment: `In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin` (Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write it like this.

```
<a href="/admin/con/image/StudentImportFileTemplate_Create.csv">Download the document</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use any such attribute to start a file download.

Just use:

```
<a href="/admin/con/image/StudentImportFileTemplate_Create.csv">Download</a>
```

If your CSV is being opened rather than getting downloaded and still want to use the download attribute, here's the right way to do it:

http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute