# Download attribute not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm trying to let the user download some data as a CSV (text) file, using Javascript and the HTML5 Download attribute (http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

The data is formed in an array, and then added to a new Blob object.

It works perfectly in Chrome and Opera, but does not work at all in Firefox.

Original example I am attempting to copy: http://blog.eliacontini.info/post/79860720828/export-to-csv-using-javascript-the-download-attribute

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wos7cf8/5/

Javascript:

```
$('#downloadButton').click(function () {
// some data to export
var data = [{
    "title": "Book title 1",
    "author": "Name1 Surname1"
}, {
    "title": "Book title 2",
    "author": "Name2 Surname2"
}, {
    "title": "Book title 3",
    "author": "Name3 Surname3"
}, {
    "title": "Book title 4",
    "author": "Name4 Surname4"
}];

// prepare CSV data
var csvData = new Array();
csvData.push('"Book title","Author"');
data.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    csvData.push('"' + item.title + '","' + item.author + '"');
});

// download stuff
var fileName = "data.csv";
var buffer = csvData.join("\n");
var blob = new Blob([buffer], {
    "type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"
});
var link = document.createElement("a");

if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
    // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
    link.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    link.click();
} else {
    alert('CSV export only works in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.');
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toggle-button" id="downloadButton"><span>Export to CSV</span></div>
```

When I add an alert with:

```
alert(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

I get this result in Firefox:

[image: Firefox blob]

...and this result in Chrome/Opera:

[image: Chrome blob]

So it seems like it omits the URL path in Firefox for some reason.

Comment: Regarding mpeg and probably other files, if the Firefox player opens, it's because your need in `about:config` the setting `media.play-stand-alone`=`false`. It may be `media.windows-media-foundation.enabled` on Windows.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You might try adding the element to the DOM before triggering the click:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This worked for me in Firefox 34

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wos7cf8/7/

Comment: Thank you jmfolds . This is how to get the 'link' attribute of the 'a' element working in Firefox. Very helpful!

Comment: This worked great for FF but broke IE... it makes my browser go to /true. May have to adjust this to check for IE

Comment: @MattHintzke - HTML5 Download attribute is not supported in IE or Safari. http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now works for me in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: i dont need to call appendChild, removeChild on Chrome, but it is necessary on Firefox

Comment: Fixed my issue with Firefox compatibility.