# HTML anchor tag download attribute not working in Firefox for jpg and png files

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In my web application I have supported user to upload any type of document (.png, .jpg, .docx, .xls, ... )  
 I'm trying to implement download functionality for these documents.

 In Google Chrome if you click on Download link Save dialog is shown for all above documents.

 
 In Mozilla Firefox for docx and xls works fine, Save dialog is shown **but** for **.png** and **.jpg** download tag is not working as expected i.e., download dialog or Save dialog does not appear, it directly open that image.

My code:

```
<a href="/img/14340.jpg" download="14340.jpg">Download</a>
```

I have tried almost all solutions mentioned on stackoverflow and suggested by Google. But most of them says that 'check firefox version' and other changes like:
[try adding the element to the DOM before triggering the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox)

Remove filename from download tag it is of boolean type and etc.

I have also tried [w3schools lesson on anchor tag and download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_download.asp) but nothing seems to be working.

My Mozilla Firefox version is: 38.0.5

*P.S.: in chrome as well as in firefox .docs, .xls, .pdf documents work fine, problem is for .png and .jpg in firefox.*

Comment: It currently works on both firefox and chrome to me, but keep in mind that the **download** attribute is an **HTML5** feature. Did you check this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file .. Or directly this: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify despite you're not using jquery... (it works without jQuery too, though)

Comment: can you show me your complete code....May be I will be of some help to you..

Comment: It seems that it has stopped working in latest Firefox. I used to use download attribute in a bookmarklet and it was working until recently, but now I see it opens a file (.mp4) instead of showing Save dialog. Damn Firefox.

Comment: @JafferWilson: `<a href="/img/14340.jpg" download="14340.jpg">
  <i class="icon-download" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;"></i>
 </a>` I do not have any javascript function on this icon-download click. If you try [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download), it works perfectly on firefox. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Please can you send the code with the help of jsfiddle..

Comment: ok then try removing the the name of file and just keep it download..ok.

Comment: How does facebooks 'Download' Option works? On clicking it, shows Opening <filename with extension> in Firefox. Does anybody know how to implement this type of saving image/documents?

Answer (score 4):

Firefox will handle png and jpeg using default handling, which is to inline them in the document. When clicking a link, even if download attribute is defined, seem to make Firefox think it has a new image ignoring the download aspect of it. This may be a temporary bug.

Here is a way, admittedly not super-elegant, to get around this problem forcing the image to be interpreted as an octet-stream.

It does not work inline on Stackoverflow so you have to **[test it on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/szgh2fjj/)**

The code does the following:

- Scans the document for a-tags.
- Those which has `data-link` set will have a common click-handler attached.
- When clicked the link is extracted from the `data-link` attribute (`href` is se to #), loaded as an ArrayBuffer via XHR (CORS requirements applies, not a problem in this case), and is converted to an Object-URL with the Blob set to mime-type `octet/stream`
- The Object URL is set as `window.location` to redirect to this binary data which will make the browser ask user to download the file instead.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"), i = 0, lnk;

while(lnk = links[i++]) {
  if (lnk.dataset.link.length) lnk.onclick = toBlob;
}

function toBlob(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var lnk = this, xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", lnk.dataset.link);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.overrideMimeType("octet/stream");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      window.location = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

**Example tag:**

```html
<a href="#" data-link="image.jpg">Click to download</a>
```

The drawback is that you'll loose the extension in the filename.

This is also possible to do using a Data-URL, but a data-url has a 166% overhead compared to using ArrayBuffer and a blob.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with firefox not handling the download attribute, even for same-domain files.

My target files are actually hosted on AWS, so they are cross-domain. I got around this with a same-domain endpoint that downloads the remote file and pipes it to the client.

```
const express = require('express')
const {createWriteStream} = require('fs')
const downloadVideo = (url) => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const filePath = `/tmp/neat.mp4`
  const ws = createWriteStream(filePath)
  request(url, {}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) { return reject(error) }
    resolve(filePath)
  }).pipe(ws)
})}

app.get('/api/download', async (req, res) => {
  const videoPath = await downloadVideo(req.query.url)
  res.sendFile(videoPath)
})
```

On the client, I send the file path to the download endpoint to get a blob back, which is then converted to an object url. From there, it's standard download attribute stuff.

```
async download(remoteFilePath){
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  const dlURL = `/api/download?url=${encodeURIComponent(remoteFilePath)}`
  const blob = await fetch(dlURL).then(res => res.blob())
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  a.setAttribute('download', 'cool.mp4')
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  a.remove()
}
```

Answer (score -4):

As you are using HTML5 attribute, each browser handling differently. So use https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify for client side forceful download instead of viewing in browser.

Comment: Note that this solution requires Flash installed "The end user must have Flash 10 or higher installed for this plugin to work."