# Firefox - Download attribute not working for images

Tags: html, firefox, download

What is the best way to download an image by clicking a button in Firefox? I currently am using this, and it only works in Chrome:

```
<a href="img/image.jpg" download>Download image</a>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801195/html-anchor-tag-download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox-for-jpg-and-png-files

Comment: @Aurasphere That fix did not work for me

Comment: what happens? does it display the image or does it give you an error message like file not found? because it works for me on FF.

Comment: @SergioFernandez If you are referring to this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/szgh2fjj/, then nothing happens when I click the download link. My FF is up to date.

Comment: both work. the top is simpler just one line. they don't work from jsfiddle in FF, maybe its a limitation of the site. but it does work if you have it on your local machine or on a live server. so, the problem might not be your code, but it might be a issue with jsfiddle.net and FF. however, there seem to be code that work around this issue on JSFiddle. look at this link his code can download the image: https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/ and other people have other work around that work. but out side of JSFiddle, your code  works.