# How to download a mp3 file in Firefox using Anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, html5-audio

In my website I'm trying to download a file using following code. It works normally in chrome and downloads the file. But in firefox its opening file in other tab and playing it. Please suggest any other method to download mp3

FYI: Files are getting downloaded from other websites and please give me an answer related to mp3 file download not any text downloads. May be it is Related to cross origin downloads.

Code:

```
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href= 'http://www.example.com/Albums/NameOfalbum/songname.mp3';  //Cross Origin
    anchor.download= 'FileName.mp3';
    anchor.target='_blank';
    anchor.id='download';
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 )
         anchor.click();
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 )
         $("#download")[0].click();
```

Comment: thats how different browsers deal with it. have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root

Comment: @Alex Please give an answer. unable to understand your link clearly.

Comment: Can you use php for this?

Comment: On server side, specify content type for the resource. Otherwise it's all up to the browser vendors.

Comment: In FF you have to append the anchor in the document before calling `anchor.click()`.

Comment: @Kaiido, I did that thing also, even that is not downloading, only playing the song

Comment: Ah I missed something in your code : is your page hosted on `abc.com` ? If not, this is normal, you can't make cross-origin downloads like that.

Comment: @Kaiido, Please help me how to do Cross-Origin Downloads. FYI Chrome is downloading the file know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden iframe like.

```
function downloadURL(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
        iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;
};
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="downloadURL('path/of/mp3/file')">Download File</a>
```

Or if you want to use server side language like PHP then please follow this link.

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/php-download-file-script/

Comment: This is also playing the song. Not downloading it.

Comment: can you use php for this?

Comment: No I cant use PHP

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$('#downloadButton').click(function () {
    // some data to export
    var data = [{
        "title": "Book title 1",
        "author": "Name1 Surname1"
    }, {
        "title": "Book title 2",
        "author": "Name2 Surname2"
    }, {
        "title": "Book title 3",
        "author": "Name3 Surname3"
    }, {
        "title": "Book title 4",
        "author": "Name4 Surname4"
    }];

    // prepare CSV data
    var csvData = new Array();
    csvData.push('"Book title","Author"');
    data.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        csvData.push('"' + item.title + '","' + item.author + '"');
    });

    // download stuff
    var fileName = "data.csv";
    var buffer = csvData.join("\n");
    var blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        "type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"
    });
    var link = document.createElement("a");

    if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
        // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
        link.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
        alert('CSV export only works in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.');
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="toggle-button" id="downloadButton"><span>Export to CSV</span>
</div>
```

[Download attribute not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox)

PS:
[HTML anchor tag download attribute not working in Firefox for jpg and png files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801195/html-anchor-tag-download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox-for-jpg-and-png-files)

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"), i = 0, lnk;

while(lnk = links[i++]) {
  if (lnk.dataset.link.length) lnk.onclick = toBlob;
}

function toBlob(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var lnk = this, xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", lnk.dataset.link);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.overrideMimeType("octet/stream");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      window.location = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" data-link="image.jpg">Click to download</a>
```