# html download attribute not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Aim: download image automatically

Problem: the code works perfectly in Chrome and Opera, but not Firefox. Why and how to fix it?

Code:

```
<body>
    <a id="url" href="http://www.elkaderchildcare.com/images/abc_02.jpg" download><img src="http://www.elkaderchildcare.com/images/abc_02.jpg"></img></a>
    <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("url");
            a.click();
    </script></body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Specific version of ff.

Comment: any error message from console?

Comment: It's actually Iceweasel 38.2.1. Iceweasel redirects to the image link directly and does not show download dialog. In Chrome and Opera, they show the download dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip off the protocol part and try like this

```js
var a = document.getElementById("url");
a.click();
```

```css
.fc_card-container{
  border-radius:6px;
  background:red;
  padding:5px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:5px;

}
```

```html
<a id="url" href="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/240px-Example.svg.png" download>
<img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/240px-Example.svg.png"></a>
```

This will work in chrome & FF . In FF you may see connection is untrusted but you can still accept and download it