# download attribute on anchor element doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor element like below :

```
<a class="button button--simple-black" href="/-/media/Project/Test/Continent/test.png" download onclick="window.location = '/'">Download Wallpaper</a>
```

I'm expecting when the user clicks on the link, the image file gets downloaded and the user gets redirected to home page.

It works as I'm expecting it to, in Chrome and Edge but in Firefox, instead of download, the image is opened in the active tab and quickly redirects to home page.

Is there any workaround for this? or am I missing something that causes this malfunctioning?

Comment: are you using `file://`protocoll ?

Comment: Doesnt your `onclick` just cancel that? It gets executed before the default click handler, which would initiate your download... You would need to delay forwarding a bit until the default event has done its thing.

Comment: @johnSmith it's http.

Comment: @somethinghere The problem is that in Firefox, instead of downloading, it actually renders the image in the current tab. in Chrome and Edge, it downloads the file which is what i'm expecting and should be the currect behaviour of `download` attribute i put on the anchor element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox)