# browser only downloads 10 images at once (JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, download

there is a limit of downloads that can be done at the same time and that limit is 10 how can I change the code so that it allows more than 10 at the same time ?

```
 transferFiles(){
      this.checkMark = true

  let i = 0
   this.finalImages.forEach((image) =>{
      i++
      saveAs(image, 'imagem'+i);
    
      })
    
  } 
  
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can provide the correct information that we need to answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How in JS to download more than 10 files in browser including Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244902/how-in-js-to-download-more-than-10-files-in-browser-including-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if there is a restriction on the number of simultaneous downloads, why not try setting a timeout so they don't fire at the same time?

```
transferFiles(){
   this.checkMark = true

   let i = 0
   this.finalImages.forEach((image) =>{
       setTimeout(function(){
           saveAs(image, 'imagem'+(i+1));
       }, i++ * 500);
   });
}
```

Comment: it worked ! thanks for the help next time the question will be more clear

Comment: This can still cause problems on slow connections / huge files?

Comment: I mean the objective is just pictures of small size no other type os files