# Firefox download tag hyperlink not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have applied a code to download data in CSV format in angular.
Here is my code

```js
downloadStudentCSV() {
  // var data = [];
  var data = ['First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name', 'Email Address', 'Phone', 'Date of Birth', 'Address Line 1', 'Address Line 2', 'City', 'State', 'Post Code', 'Country', 'Student Visa Expiry Date'];

  const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value; // specify how you want to handle null values here
  // const header = Object.keys(data[0]);
  const header = data;
  // console.log(header);
  let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
  csv.unshift(header.join(','));
  // let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');
  let csvArray = "\ufeff" + csv.join('\r\n');

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var blob = new Blob([csvArray], {
      type: 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8'
    }),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  a.href = url;
  a.download = "studentInfoFile.csv";
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  a.remove();
}
```

The issue is that I'm unable to download the file in Firefox but it's working fine in Chrome.
Can anybody help plz?

Comment: Also you might want to not revokeObjectURL immediately - not sure how the timing is on this

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js works pretty much on all browsers

Comment: Here is the answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox